# Teleporting Different Players in Different Locations

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Say there are 6 players in a map, and you want to teleport all of them in 6 different locations. You cannot teleport them by name since there will be different players every time. What command do I use?

Comment: Do these 6 players each need to go to 6 different specific locations or are you just spreading them out?

Comment: It is more of a spread out, I’m doing a pvp map and I need to have them all /tp in the same map. So similar coordinates. One of my maps has a giant circle layout (a tower) and I want to make the spawn (/tp) on the circumference

Comment: Another thing I wanna ask is how do I /testfor a specific player order? Ex: /testfor @e[type=  <player 1>   ] /testfor @e[type=    <player 2>    ]

Comment: Ask that in a _Different post_

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [spreadplayers command](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#spreadplayers):

```
spreadplayers <x> <z> <spreadDistance> <maxRange> <respectTeams> <player …>
```

- x and z specify the center coordinates of the spread area
- spreadDistance specifies the minimum distance between the spread players
- maxRange specifies the maximum distance they will be spread from center
- respectTeams is true or false and specifies whether to keep teams together
- player specifies the player(s) to spread

An example:

```
spreadplayers 50 100 25 200 false @a
```

This will spread all players to random surface locations in a 400×400 block area centered on (50,100), with a minimum distance between players of 25 blocks.

Comment: How does respect teams work? I have a team map and I’d like to split the player count into two. Sometimes there’s 3 players, sometimes there’s 6 players. So 3 </= x >/= 6

Comment: 'If true, targets on the same team will be teleported to the same location.' from the linked wiki in the answer.  It will only work with teams which are already setup.  It will not work to evenly split the players into teams.

Comment: How do you setup a team?

Comment: Here is the wiki on [scoreboard teams](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Scoreboard#Teams_commands) and here is a [DigMinecraft tutorial on using the scoreboard](https://www.digminecraft.com/game_commands/scoreboard_command.php) which includes a section on teams.  It sounds like you are new to commands, I recommend reading both of those.  If you are planning to work with commands a bit, [the wiki on commands](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Commands) is a resource you should get very comfortable with.  I reference it often. Any other questions, my discord tag is in my profile.